# MVC suspect no data passing between view and controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I'm new to MVC and quite confused. Two main views with different display pages are being used, Index and DisplayPrediction. I tried using data annotation to validate data in the submission form, but it only shows the error messages and doesn't prevent loading of the second view. The biggest problem, though, is that the information entered into the text boxes seem to simply reset to default when the first view returns. Help would very much be appreciated :) Here's my current code:

This is the Model, I keep the fields that need to be gotten from the user here, as well as the program's functionality (the processing on the fields that will generate the output that should be displayed on the second view):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MvcHaberman.Models
{
public class HabermanPrediction
{
    [Required]
    [Range(0,100)]
    public int age { set; get; }
    [Required]
    [Range(58, 69)]
    public int year { set; get; }
    [Required]
    public int axNodes { set; get; }
    [Required]
    [Range(1, 2, ErrorMessage="Survived = 1; Did not survive = 2")]
    public int survival { set; get; }

    public string answer { set; get; }

    public void generatePrediction()
    {
        StreamWriter i = new StreamWriter(@"input.arff");
        i.WriteLine(@"relation haberman\n\n@attribute     Age_of_patient_at_time_of_operation INTEGER\n@attribute Patients_year_of_operation  {58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69}\n@attribute Number_of_positive_axillary_nodes_detected INTEGER\n@attribute Survival_status {1,2}\n\n@data");
        i.WriteLine(age + "," + year + "," + axNodes + "," + survival);
        i.Close();
        Process genPrediction = new Process();
        genPrediction.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            FileName = @"habermanCommand.bat",
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            Arguments = "cmd.exe"
        };
        genPrediction.Start();
        genPrediction.WaitForExit();
        genPrediction.Dispose();

        StreamReader readPrediction = new StreamReader(@"output.txt");
        string line = readPrediction.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
        if (line.Contains(':'))
        {
            string[] part = line.Split(':');
            if (part[2].Contains('+'))
            {
                string[] prediction = part[2].Split('+');
                if (part[2][0] == '1')
                    answer = "\t(Survived)\t\tProbability that your assessment was  incorrect:\t" + (Convert.ToDecimal(prediction[1].Trim()) * 100) + "%";
                else answer = "\t(Did not Survive)\tProbability that your assessment was incorrect:\t" + (Convert.ToDecimal(prediction[1].Trim()) * 100) + "%";
            }
            else
            {
                string line1 = "";
                string lineTrimmed = "";
                for (int j = 1; j < part[2].Length; j++)
                    line1 += part[2][j];
                for (int l = 0; l < line1.Length; l++)
                    if (line1[l] != ' ')
                        lineTrimmed += line1[l];
                if (part[2][0] == '1')
                    answer = "\t(Survived)\t\tProbability that your assessment was correct:\t" + (Convert.ToDecimal(lineTrimmed) * 100) + "%";
                else
                    answer = "\t(Did not Survive)\tProbability that your assessment was correct:\t" + (Convert.ToDecimal(lineTrimmed) * 100) + "%";
            }
            }
            line = readPrediction.ReadLine();
        }
        readPrediction.Close();
    }

}
}
```

The controller specifies the two views that between which the data should flow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcHaberman.Models;
using DataAnnotationsExtensions;

namespace MvcHaberman.Controllers
{
public class HabermanController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HabermanPrediction obj = new HabermanPrediction();

        if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            return Redirect("/Habberman/Index");
        }
        else return View(obj);
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult DisplayPrediction(HabermanPrediction objOut)
    {   
        objOut.generatePrediction();
        return View(objOut);
    }
}
}
```

Submit view:

```
@model MvcHaberman.Models.HabermanPrediction
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>HabermanPrediction</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.age)

    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.age)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.age) 
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.year)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field" >
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.year)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.year) 
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.axNodes)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field" >
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.axNodes)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.axNodes)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.survival)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field" > 
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.survival)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.survival)
    </div>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Generate Prediction", "DisplayPrediction")

    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Output view:

```
`@model MvcHaberman.Models.HabermanPrediction`
`@using MvcHaberman.Models`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>DisplayPrediction</title>
</head>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<body>
<div class= "label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.answer)
</div>
<div>
    <h1>@Model.age</h1>
    <h2>@Model.answer</h2>
</div>
</body>
}
</html>
```

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: I am glad you realized what I was referring to, non the less.

Answer (score 0):

When you use View(obj) method, it generates new View with default model named obj. so when the page refresh, default value of html elements set to your model parameters(in this scenario obj parameters).

Comment: So how do I assign the parameters of obj the values that are entered into the editor fields? I removed the obj, it seems like it might have been unnecessary after all, but the parameters of objOut are still the default values (null and 0s).

Comment: Assign id parameter for BeginForm then Rename objOut to assigned name. I think your problem is related to serialization.